# Integrate Cypress with Robot Testing Framework?

Tags: robotframework, cypress

I need to evaluate the best suitable end-to-end-testing library for our React Web App. One requirement would be to integrate this e2e-library with the Robot Framework, that our team currently uses for our tests.

Does anyone know if and how one could integrate Cypress as an e2e-library with the Robot Framework?

UPDATE: Possible scenario could be:
With a simple one line command we would like to execute all our Robot tests and aggregate them in one results file. It would be nice, if there is a way to write Cypress e2e tests inside a robot file, as you can with Selenium, or at least trigger the cypress JS test files and retrieve their results and somehow merge them with the results from the other Robot tests

UPDATE 2: We switched to using the new Robot Library "**Browser**", which is like Robot Selenium just better in every way. Browser uses the Browser Automation Tool Playwright, the spiritual successor of Puppeteer, under the hood. Working with Browser makes a lot of fun, its API is very intuitive, versatile and potent. So at the moment, we completely dropped the idea of integrating Robot with Cypress. Browser does a wonderful job.

Comment: Cypress is an independent JS framework used to write tests, but you already have your tests written on the Robot Framework. > With a simple one line command we would like to execute all our Robot tests and aggregate them in one results file
> Blockquote Can't you simply use a **CLI/Reporting** tool for your Robot Framework to achieve this? Please elaborate more on what Cypress feature you need/ why Cypress?.

Comment: Thank your for the answer, Getulio. I thought Cypress is primarily meant for end-to-end tests. We are currently using the selenium-library for Robot, which I am not very happy about, since I prefer using Cypress for e2e tests. But all our other tests (for software other than the react ui) are written with Robot. Thus, we need to integrate the ui e2e tests within the Robot framework.

Could you elaborate further what you mean with a CLI/Reporting tool?

Comment: I am understanding you would like to see an aggregated report containing test results of 2 different testing frameworks (Cypress, RobotFramework).
There is no such way to add one testing framework into another (this would basically mean rewriting all tests in the other framework).
I believe what you need is a setup that runs both frameworks for you, and shows the results in the same place.
How are these tests run? Are they manually triggered or do you have some sort of continuous integration for it? A dev, tae or devops from your team should be familiar with these concepts.

Comment: Yes, you are right in your assumptions and yes, I would agree that the only solution at the moment would be a script that starts both the robot and cypress tests and then adds results form both frameworks into a total test summary. At the moment, we kind of accepted working with robot and selenium although I am not very fond of it. Yes, the tests are triggered in a pipeline on every push to the repo and every merge into master. @GetulioGasparottoDadald